# What does "Not allowed to load local resource" mean?

Tags: xml, xslt, browser

I am trying to view an XML file associated with XSLT:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="upit.xsl"?>
```

When I view it, it shows:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

And on the console

> Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: Your question is lacking. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
In this state of the question, my recommended solution would be "verify the parser is allowed to load the local ressource (of course!)".

Comment: Which software do you use to "run" the XML associated with an XSLT stylesheet? Do you load the XML from the file system or from an HTTP server? How does the association (`<?xml-stylesheet?>`?) of the XML with the XSLT look like exactly?

Comment: I load it from file system. <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="upit.xsl"?>

Comment: And which software gives the error message " Not allowed to load local resource"? Chrome for instance is known to require to be started with lowered security settings to apply XSLT from the file system. Have you tried a different browser like Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are violating the security protocol of the system you're trying to use to access a local resource, in this case, to apply your stylesheet.   The general idea is to protect browser users from malicious access to files on their file system.  While well intended, the rule often frustrates developers during development and testing.

The solution is to serve the XML and XSLT from a web server rather than from the local file system.